# В чем может быть ошибка в моем коде? Старался максимально кратко писать, чтобы сохранить время на ЕГЭ

Tags: python, олимпиада

В чем может быть ошибка в моем коде? Старался максимально кратко его написать, чтобы сохранить время на ЕГЭ. Ответ 2304 не верен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
k=0
s='01234567'
for x1 in s:
    for x2 in s:
        for x3 in s:
            for x4 in s:
                for x5 in s:
                    for x6 in s:
                        x=x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6
                        if (x.count('3') == 0) and all(x.count(i) == 1 for i in x) and (sum([1 for i in range(len(x)-1) if (int(x[i]) % 2 == 0) and (int(x[i+1]) % 2 == 0)]) >= 2):
                        k+=1
print(k)
```

Comment: А ведущие нули разрешены? Наверное, надо выкинуть числа с ведущими нулями. А насчёт 3 так проще её сразу из перебора исключить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шестизначное число не может начинаться с нуля.

Не ошибка, но просто незачем включать в перебор тройку и затем исключать варианты с ней

Comment: Ой, точно, спасибо большое, забыл о нулях в начале числа